# How to access controller via URL in an MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've yet not found a very simple MVC framework. How do frameworks make it possible to access a controller by just an URL? I think it has got to do with the `QUERY_STRING` but isn't it suppose to have a `?`?

```
http://localhost/public/controllername
```

and `localhost/public` is located at:

```
C:\wamp\www\public\
```

which contains an index.php

Comment: You can check [Symfony2](http://symfony.com), and it's micro version, [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). It's a decoupled PHP framework, and you can only use the components you need. The creator of Symfony has [a series of blog posts](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) explaining how to build a framework with Symfony components. :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is done through the use of `.htaccess` rewrites ([Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)):

1. You use `.htaccess` rewrites to direct every query that is not a static file to your main entry point, for example `index.php`, assuming you use PHP as your server side language.
2. You then parse the URI from within `index.php` and establish some routes in your application.

**Quick example:**

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

`index.php` file:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = explode('/', $uri);
// assuming you want /controller/action/* mapping
$controller = 'index'; // default
$action = 'index'; // default
if (isset($parts[0])) $controller = $parts[0];
if (isset($parts[1])) $action = $parts[1];
// now, you'd try to establish some logic to test wether this controller/action
// actually exists, and load it. I'll leave this up to you.
```

This, of course, is just a quick and rough example, but should give you an idea of how to do this.

Comment: but `$parts[0]` is empty. And what if I place them in subfolders, the content of `$parts` changes.

Comment: @JackSpairow this is not a site where you will receive a solution you can simple copy/paste into your application. The above code is intended as a pointer and not as a working solution. The best way to get this thing working is by trying it yourself.

Comment: I was just trying to understand.

Answer (score -1):

it works parsing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']